# How do I disallow a button from submitting my form in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two buttons in my django site's form, the first one is supposed to only call a javscript function and the second one is supposed to submit the form.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.title|as_crispy_field }}
     <br/>
     {{ form.body|as_crispy_field }}
     <button class="btn mt-3" onclick="insertText('HELLO')">Insert Text</button>
     <br/>
     <button class="btn btn-success mt-3" >Submit!</button>
 </form>
```

My 'views.py' file contains following code for this page:

```
class Posts(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = PostForm()
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-publish_date')
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'posts': posts
        }

        return render(request, 'posts/view_posts.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.publisher = request.user
            new_post.save()
            form = PostForm() 

        return redirect('view-posts')
```

My problem is the 1st button that is supposed to be only calling a javascript function is also making a POST request and submitting the form.

Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name your button as

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.title|as_crispy_field }}
     <br/>
     {{ form.body|as_crispy_field }}
     <button class="btn mt-3" onclick="insertText('HELLO')" name="not_save_button">Insert Text</button>
     <br/>
     <button class="btn btn-success mt-3" name="save_button">Submit!</button>
 </form>
```

And in post method of your view:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid() and 'save_button' in request.POST:
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.publisher = request.user
            new_post.save()
            form = PostForm() 

        return redirect('view-posts')
```

Comment: I'm still having a bit of a problem in this, whenever I press the "not_save_button" the site refreshes and clears the form, because the post request is redirecting me back to the site again.